# Carousel bootstrap with angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to use carousel from bootstrap with two predefined templates. I need the carousel to show brand tab when I press button on the right, and when I press button on left to slide back to time temlate. Can anyone help me how to use angular carousel in my case. Here is my HTML

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
             <div class="container row">
                 <label class="form-group lable-margin">Date</lable>
             </div>
            <div class="container row">
               <label class="form-group">From: </label> [[stuff.filtersAll.START_DATE]]
            </div>
         <div class="container row">
              <label class="form-group">To: </label> [[stuff.filtersAll.END_DATE]]
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="container row">
               <label class="form-group lable-margin">Time</label>
           </div>
           <div class="container row">
               <label class="form-group">From: </label> [[stuff.filtersAll.TIME_FROM]]
           </div>
        <div class="container row">
              <label class="form-group">To: </label> [[stuff.filtersAll.TIME_TO]]
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
    <div class="item">
           <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="brads in stuff.filtersAll.BRAND">
              <li class="list-group-item">[[brand.NAME]]</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have any building option for `right click`. Only have `click`. But you can make a directive like this for `right click`

```
app.directive('ngRightClick', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.ngRightClick);
        element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
            });
        });
    };
});
```

For left click use regular ng-click. In your html code write like this

```
<div ng-click="doWhenLeftClick()" ng-right-click="doWhenRightClick()">
    // you html code hear
</div>
```